# Синтаксис bash скрипта

Tags: unix, solaris, bash, linux

Я новичок в `linux` (поэтому прошу отнестить с пониманием) и поэтому хочу задать такой вопрос: Как будет выглядеть `bash`-скрипт, который выполняет следующие действия

```
cd /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin
./hadoop namenode -format
./start-all.sh
./hadoop fs -rmr hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output
./hadoop fs -rmr hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input
./hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/input
./readwritepaths
./hadoop fs -put /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt
./hadoop jar /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/ParallelIndexation.jar org.myorg.ParallelIndexation /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output -D mapred.map.tasks=1 1> resultofexecute.txt 2>&1
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и будет. Добавьте первую строку

```
 #!/bin/bash
 а здесь Ваш текст
```

только каждая команда, естественно, в отдельной строке. Видимо у Вас  при копипасте в текст вопроса

```
./hadoop fs -put /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt   hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt
```

вот эта, например, команда разбилась на две строки